# F# reading and writing to and from unmanaged data

Tags: f#, unmanaged

I'm exploring low level programming in F#, I do know about the risk and general "don't do this", that is not what I'm asking for.

I'm currently trying the basic stuff of just getting things to work.

right now I having the problem that I got some simple type (code below) and I put some data into the memory and trying to read that data as the struct. but it keeps thronging the System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException saying I'm trying to read protected memory?

```
#nowarn "9"
open FSharp.NativeInterop
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

type msgtype = OK = 0 | ERR = 1
[<type: Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)>]
type msg  =
    [<field: FieldOffsetAttribute(0); MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)>] 
    val tp : byte
    [<field: FieldOffsetAttribute(1); MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)>]
    val content : int


let memory = 
    Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024)

let read n  =
    let adr = memory
    let ptr = NativePtr.ofNativeInt<_> memory
    NativePtr.read ptr



let write item adr =
    let adr' = memory + adr
    let ptr = NativePtr.ofNativeInt adr'
    NativePtr.write ptr item

write 1uy memory
write 654 (memory+1n)
let m : msg = read memory

Marshal.FreeHGlobal memory
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem my self.

Apparently the write function was the problem.

I changed it to

```
let write add item = 
    NativePtr.write (NativePtr.ofNativeInt<_> add) item
```

and it just worked.

can say if it is the declarings that course to problem only that somehow it is different?